# Web Deploy SQL Server gives deadlock when creating a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, deadlock, webdeploy

We use web deploy packages to create and deploy a SQL Server database, when running it we encounter on a specific stored procedure the following error:

> Error: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The
>   approximate location of the error was between lines '1481' and '1586'
>   of the script. The verbose log may have more information about the
>   error. The command started with :
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_MyCoolStoredProcedure
>   Error: Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process
>   and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>   Error count: 1."

When we run the database script that is in the package using SQL Server Management Studio everything works fine so there are no errors in the script, anyone has an idea on what is going wrong, the verbose option doesn't give any better error message :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the project file, set transaction="false" for every sql script element